# PHP preg_replace regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to remove anything before a given character and anything after a given character with preg_replace using a regular expression? Of course this could be done in many other ways like explode and striping the string. But I am curious about preg_replace and regex.

So the only thing I need from the string below is **03b** and remove every thing before/and slash (/) and after/and dot (.)

```
$string = 'rmbefore/03b.rmafter'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean to say you want the string between `/` and `.` ?

Comment: See [regex design tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) and [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) to learn the syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use backreferences in preg_replace to do this:

```
preg_replace('#.*/([^\.]+)\..*#', '$1', $input);
```

This searches for anything up to a slash, then as much of the following string that is not a dot, put this in group 1 (thats the '()' around it), followed by a dot and something else and replaces it with the contents of group 1 (which is the expression within parentheses and should be "03b" in your example). Here is a good website about regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
$s = preg_replace("#^.*/(.*?)\\..*$#","$1",$string)
```

Explanation:

```
  ^     matches start of string
 .*     matches a string of arbitrary characters (greedy)
 /      matches the /
 (.*?)  matches a string of arbirtrary characters (non-greedy)
 \.     matches a dot
 .*     matches a string of arbitrary characters
 $      matches end of string
```

Comment: Your forgot to add delimiter to your regex.

Comment: thanks, I don't know the php regex syntax that well. Why does it require a delimiter when it's already in a string? I mean, I understand putting it between delimiters (Perl), putting it in a string (Python), but why both?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this case, it would be over kill. You can just use the build in [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) functions.

```
$from = strpos($string, '/') + 1;
$to = strpos($string, '.');

echo substr($string, $from, $to - $from);

// echos 03b
```

Ofcause you can do this in one line, the above was just for clarity

```
echo substr($string, strpos($string, '/') + 1, strpos($string, '.') - strpos($string, '/') - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('~^.*/(.*?)\..*$~',"$1",$string);
```